# Multilevel package - Java

Tags: java, package, noclassdeffounderror

I am just a newbie in java And i am using packages for the first time.
I am trying to make packages in this hierarchy:

> /chess/game/Pieces.class
>
> /chess/Board.class imports Pieces
>
> /Game.java imports Board

I compiled using just `javac filename.java` to get the class files.

Game.java doesn't use any of the methods and variables of the Pieces.class just to be sure.
All the Classes,Functions  and Variables are public. 
I tested the board.java with a main and it works perfectly fine.But when i use it as a package it doesn't work and i get class not found.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: game/Pieces
        at chess.Board.initializeboard(Board.java:31)
        at Game.main(Game.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: game.Pieces
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        at chess.Board.initializeboard(Board.java:31)
        at Game.main(Game.java:14)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.execute(Main.java:415)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:192)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:132)
```

I cannot import both the classes in Game.java cause i made a // package game; in Pieces.class 
so i cannot import it as // import chess.game.Pieces; in Game.java .

If this is illegal.Is there some other OOP approach?

EDIT-
The code i used-
Pieces.java -(compiled it to .class file)

```
package game;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class  Pieces{
public enum Type {ROOKE,KNIGHT,BISHOP,KING,QUEEN,PAWN};

public boolean alive = true;
public boolean white = false;
public boolean firstmove = false;
public int mx;
public int my;
public Type types;

public JButton button=new JButton();
public void setButton(JButton b){
                        this.button=b;}  

}
```

Board.java - (compiled it to .class file)

```
package chess;

import game.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Board{

public void initializeboard(JButton [][] spots){
JFrame f = new JFrame("CHESS");
f.setVisible(true);
f.setSize(800,800);

GridLayout layout =new GridLayout(8,8,1,1);
f.setLayout(layout);

for(int ver=0;ver<8;ver++){
  for(int hor=0;hor<8;hor++){
      JButton button = new JButton();
      if((ver+hor)%2==0){
                    button.setBackground(Color.WHITE); }
      else{
           button.setBackground(new Color(255,205,51)); }
 Pieces p =new Pieces();
 spots[ver][hor] = button;
 p.setButton(button);
 f.add(button);
 } //close for loop
 } // close for loop
 f.revalidate();
 } //  close initializeboard
 }// close board
```

Game.java -

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import chess.Board;
public class Game{
public static void main(String [] args){

JButton [][] spots =new  JButton [8][8];

Board b =new Board();
b.initializeboard(spots); 
}
}
```

Comment: What does a "\\" package mean to you?

Comment: i just used it to seperate from the context sorry if it bothers you

Comment: You have to import it as 'chess.game.Pieces;' However you also need to put it into a directory structure that Java understands. For example, from the current directory, it should be in the file './chess/game/Pieces.class'. You create this structure by compiling with 'javac -d ./ Pieces.java.

Comment: For that to work i would have to make `Package chess.game.Pieces` in `Pieces` which class `Board` also imports and now it would break `Board.java`

Comment: Yes. All you'd have to do is to add the correct package statement or import statement.

Comment: I've been trying that but doesn't work. I would have to place `Pieces.class` in a different directory to import it in Game.java . But i already used it in Board.java so if i place it in a different directory it will still give me error cause i actually do not use any of the methods of `Pieces.java` in `Game.java` so it doesn't matter either way if i place it in 2 directories.

Comment: Trust me, it will work out if you put it in the single proper directory for it. The import is not relative to anything but the base location. You just need to compile and run everything from this directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to directory containing file `Game.java`
2. Enter this command
   `javac chess/game/Pieces.java`
3. After that, enter this command
   `javac -cp . game/Board.java`
4. After that, enter this command
   `javac -cp . Game.java`

Comment: Do i import the packages as i posted or do i have to do it differently?

Comment: @Devas you are asking me how to organize code that you have not posted. Pardon me for being so hopelessly inadequate, but if you don't show me your code, I can't tell you how to organize it. I can only answer according to the details you provided in your question. You wrote partial paths to your java class files and you also indicated which files contain import statements. Now you're asking me if what you wrote is correct. Excuse me, but based on the details you have provided, I cannot answer that question.